# Why doesn't typescript infer the final type inferred as string?

Tags: typescript

I have defined this type:

```
type StoreDataValue = string | Record<PropertyKey, any>;
```

And I have a parameter `value` that is of this type.

First I create a temp variable and assign it to `value`.

I then do a check to see if it's different than `string` use `JSON.stringify` to convert it to a `string`.

But typescript doesn't infer that the final result is `string`.

It shows this error when I try to use the final `parsedValue`:

> Argument of type 'StoreDataValue' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
> Type 'Record<PropertyKey, any>' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2345)

The code is the following:

```
type StoreDataValue = string | Record<PropertyKey, any>;

const storeData = async (key: string, value: StoreDataValue) => {
  try {
    let parsedValue = value;
    if (typeof parsedValue !== "string") {
      parsedValue = JSON.stringify(value);
    } else {
      parsedValue = value;
    }

    await AsyncStorage.setItem(key, parsedValue);

  } catch (e) {
    // ...
  }
};
```

If I just change the line `typeof parsedValue ...` to `typeof value ...` then the inference works.

Am I doing something wrong or not seeing the obvious?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that this:

```
if (typeof parsedValue !== "string") {
  parsedValue = JSON.stringify(value);
}
```

narrows ONLY the type of `parsedValue` to `string` but does NOT automatically do any narrowing on the type of `value`. So, after this line the TypeScript type checker still thinks that `value` is of type `string | Record<PropertyKey, any>` and when you assign `value` to `parsedValue` in the `else` clause, the TypeScript checker thinks that you might revert the type of `parsedValue` back to `string | Record<PropertyKey, any>`.

If you remove the `else` clause of the if-statement, you would see that the error disappears. The reason for this is that there will no longer be a code path which assigns a value of type `string | Record<PropertyKey, any>` (i.e. the type of the `value` parameter) to `parsedValue` after `parsedValue` has been narrowed to `string`:

```
    let parsedValue = value;
    if (typeof parsedValue !== "string") {
      parsedValue = JSON.stringify(value);
    }

    await AsyncStorage.setItem(key, parsedValue); // This works just fine
```